# How do I rotate the orientation in the ghostscript plot for ps file?

Tags: linux, ghostscript, postscript

I am plotting the (postscript) ps file using the ghostscript in the terminal.

When I use the command"gs file.ps", it always gives the portrait orientation like following
[image]

do you know how could I rotate the plot with 90 degrees with landscape orientation? thanks a lot.